# Is it possible to add two checboxes in single list item using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

We are working in a vb application and we are in need of the below UI

[UI Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfGnx.png)

We have fetched a result set and appended the result set in a checkedlistbox which automatically creates a checkbox for the prescribed list of items. We are not able to add another checkbox to the right portion of the list item. Kindly help us.
We have populated the items and displayed the left hand side checkbox as per the snippet above
 For Each b In a.Items

```
        If Me.selb.Text = show Or b.Selected = True Then

           Me.chklistbox.Items.Add(b.Text & " (" & b.Code & ")")            
           Me.chklistbox.SetItemChecked(i, b.Selected)    
           i += 1

        End If
```

We are not able to populate the second checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add two or more checkboxes to a [CheckedListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx) component as it

> Displays a ListBox in which a check box is displayed to the left of
>   each item

and although there is a [MultiColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) property, it only rearranges items which is not what you need. You would need another multicolumn WinForms component such as DatGridView or a ListView.